# JPA: The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have deployed my application in JBoss 7.1 and database connection is done in JPA persistence.xml. Here is configuration

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="Prashant11" />
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.URL"  value="false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/"/>
```

Getting Caused by: EJB Invocation failed on component ProfileSession for method public abstract java.util.List sp.ProfileSessionRemote.getTopProfile(int[]): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections

Comment: Errm, I'd assume that "hibernate.connection.URL" should be a URL! Besides which you are specifying the URL as "javax.persistence.jdbc.url", yet then miss off all of the other STANDARD javax.persistence.jdbc properties. Suggest you read a basic tutorial on JPA

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to connect using a standalone connection i.e.

```
<persistence-unit name="justshop-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">.
```

It could be due to:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.URL"  value="false"/>
```

use

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url"  value="false"/>
```

instead. case sensitive.

Or

**Configure datasource:**

if you are using JTA as transaction type in persistence unit and since you are trying to connect from EJB which is conatiner managed context and hence it would default to JTA transaction. You would need to configure datasource connection.

These are the steps for the same used for mysql datasource config in JBoss 7.1:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExpenseDS" pool-name="ExpenseDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/expense</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>username</user-name>
                        <password>pwd</password>
                    </security>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

- also add the driver entry in standalone.xml as shown below:

> ```
> <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
> <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
> <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
> </driver>
> ```

- Create a module.xml file as shown below

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>
> <!--
>   ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
>   ~ Copyright 2010, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
>   ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
>   ~ distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
>   ~
>   ~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
>   ~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
>   ~ published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
>   ~ the License, or (at your option) any later version.
>   ~
>   ~ This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
>   ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>   ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
>   ~ Lesser General Public License for more details.
>   ~
>   ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
>   ~ License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
>   ~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
>   ~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
>   -->
>
> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
>
>     <resources>
>         <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar"/>
>         <!-- Insert resources here -->
>     </resources>
>     <dependencies>
>         <module name="javax.api"/>
>     </dependencies>
> </module>
> ```

- Place that along with the mysql driver jar as a module into jboss. Create a module folder in modules in jboss:
      - For ex: for mysql since we gave module as com.mysql we will create folders com/mysql and another folder main as well and place the driver class and module.xml in "com/mysql/main" (Refer to h2database configuration if you are confused)

Answer (score -1):

which version of Hibernate are you using?
It looks you mixed Hibernate 3.x and 4.x syntax in hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Hibernate 3.x

```
<properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="...."/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="...."/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="...."/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="...."/>   </properties>
```

Hibernate 4.x

```
<properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="...."/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="...."/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="...."/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="...."/>
 </properties>
```